# convert this SQL query to LINQ to Entities

Tags: linq-to-entities

Some LINQ queries still puzzle me.

In SQL I would use this:

```
SELECT count(se.IdSolicitud) as numSoli,
      (select top 1 Fini FROM SolicitudEstado as SE2 wherE SE2.idsolicitud = SE.idsolicitud AND SE2.IDESTADO=2) as Fini2,
      (select top 1 Fini FROM SolicitudEstado as SE2 wherE SE2.idsolicitud = SE.idsolicitud AND SE2.IDESTADO=3) as Fini3
  FROM [pruebas].[dbo].[SolicitudEstado] AS SE
group by se.IdSolicitud
```

In LINQ I got no idea how to approach this, can anyone help me here? I tried to convert it using linqer, but it just shows an error for this expression.

Thanks

Comment: Try something - what didn't work, or didn't work as expected? My first step would be to rewrite the query *without* sub-selects as I find JOINS more natural in both SQL and LINQ-"sql". Note that a TOP/First/Take *requires* an ORDER BY/OrderBy for consistent results where more than one result can be returned. If more than one result *can't* be returned then a simple [LEFT] JOIN will collapse down nicely.